# Adjust UICollectionView Height

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios8, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

My UICollectionview's final contentsize height will only be known after loading data. Note that I'm using a custom datasource here which is a separate class.

Where is the best place to change the UICollectionviews height?

It appears that the height is not yet known during viewdidload/loadview/viewwillappear stage. Based on logs, the height will be known during viewwilllayoutsubviews/viewdidlayoutsubviews.

Does it make sense to change frame during this stage? Please advice.

Note: 
1. UICollectionView's parent controller adds the uicollectionview using addsubview/addchild controller

2. During this process of adding the height is based on initialize value. i.e. 500.0f
3. But the uicollectionview's height will be updated to 1000.0f after executing datasource
4. Where is the best place to update uicollectionview height?

Comment: You should update the height after the data arrives and you know the correct height.